# lock all submit button before page fully rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

may i know how to use jquery to lock all the `<input type="submit/button" ..`   and only allow submit when page is fully rendered?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because of the use case, I might approach it differently. Instead of *actually* disabling the buttons, I would just not allow the submit action to work until the page is loaded. This doesn't require any changes to the existing HTML to work, and your pages won't be rendered useless when JS is disabled:

```
<script>
   // Keep all submit buttons from working by returning false from onclick handlers
   $('input:submit').live('click', function () {
      return false;
   });

   // After everything loads, remove the the "live" restriction via "die"
   $(window).load(function(){
       $('input:submit').die();
   });
</script>
```

**Update**: Forgot to mention to put both this and the `script` tag to load the jQuery library in your `<head>` if you want this solution to work. (*Thanks for reminding me Mike Sherov*).

Comment: However, this is still dependent on jquery loading before the page is fully rendered!

Comment: If jQuery is in your <head> it *will* load before the page is rendered. In fact, page rendering will halt while it loads.

Comment: Well then, if the jQuery is in the head, then the rest of the exercise is useless. :)

Comment: @Mike how is the rest of the exercise useless? In this use case, rendering a page with all the controls disabled is bad idea unless the app forces the user to have JS enabled. Loading JS in the <head> is the right choice to avoid rendering a useless page to those w/o JS enabled.

Comment: I was just joking around, meaning that the exercise looked like it was calling for non-blocking code.

Comment: @Mike Haha... its possible ;) Well, between the two of us we have the OP covered!

Comment: use `on` and `off` instead of `live` and `die`

Comment: and what about if submit is not binded to click it can also be done using enter or some keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 8):

By default, you have your submit buttons have the disabled attribute set to true:

```
<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
```

Then, once the page loads, you can do:

```
$('input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: It's actually disabled="disabled"

Comment: Edited the answer to show disabled="disabled" - it's an otherwise good answer.

Comment: @Kai, no, it's exactly what the OP wants, which is enable the elements once the page is fully rendered.

Comment: @Marko, actually, disabled will work with any value, even "false"! But still, the correct value IS "disabled", so +1 on your comment.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I usually just do <input type="button" disabled />. You can omit the value of that attribute :)

Comment: @Marko, yes, that's why it's value is unimportant and you have to do removeAttr

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":button,:submit").removeAttr("disabled");  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button 1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button 2" disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Button 3" disabled="disabled">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="form-submit" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-submit").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like

```
window.onsubmit=function(){return false;}
window.onload=function(){window.onsubmit='';}
```

I am not sure how the event bubbling would work with an onsubmit.  I'd have to test it.  Also, I don't know jquery so I'm not sure how to integrate it.